# Blackjack game for Linux or Wine?

Tags: gnome

I've been looking for a decent blackjack game that will run under linux.
I read a man page for blackjack which said it was in the gnome-games package.

I did a:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-games
```

but no blackjack showed up.

I tried Blackjack_for_the_hopelessly_luckless but it is very basic with only totals, no soft hands, no pair splitting etc.

I'm looking for a game to practice my strategy before blowing some money at the casino.

Anyone got any suggestions? Would prefer GPL but will buy a cd-rom if I have to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an answer to your question,but there are many flash games offering that amount of functionality.You will only need flash installed (install the restricted extras package).

Comment: Not an answer? Seems pretty good me. Solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Island Blackjack is freeware available at http://www.doublegames.com/isleblackjack.html#.URVqQhCtVHI -- Works great with WINE.

Answer (score 0):

Was wondering what happened to blackjack didn't Ubuntu use to come with a blackjack game?
Well I got the deb file from here: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/lucid/i386/gnome-blackjack/1:2.28.0-0ubuntu1

Answer (score 0):

The Racket programming language includes some games, including blackjack ([documentation](https://docs.racket-lang.org/games/blackjack.html)). To play blackjack, install racket (`sudo apt-get install racket`), run `plt-games` in the terminal, and click on "Blackjack":

[image: PLT Games]

[image: Blackjack game in Racket]

> Would prefer GPL but will buy a cd-rom if I have to.

PLT Games is dual-licensed under the Apache 2.0 and MIT licenses ([reference](https://github.com/racket/games/blob/v8.3/LICENSE)).